# How can I retrieve fullcalendar's next day info to fetch new events in day view?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I use full calendar v3 in agendaDay only, with hundreds of event per day, so I want to load only 1 day of events. At the initialization I loaded with a simple ajax call. But when I click on the next day I can't get to figure out, how to fetch that day's events.

I tried to find the next and prev day events also, to fetch the next (or prev) date to pass it to the ajax call but with no luck.
Can you help me out how to solve this?

This is how it's initialized now:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaDay',
  allDaySlot: false,
  slotEventOverlap: false,
  slotDuration: '00:15:00',
  nowIndicator: true,
  defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:30:00',
  events: {
    url: '/load_events',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(event, element, view,) {
        // I checked every var if it's containing useful info
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed, fullCalendar will automatically send the start and end date (of the current view) in the AJAX request it makes to your "/load_events" URL. Your server should be using those to filter the events it returns to only those which fall on or between those dates. If and when the user clicks to move the calendar to a new date, then if fullCalendar hasn't already downloaded event data for that date, it will automatically make another ajax request to your server with the new start/end date, and your server should reply with new events

Comment: So if your server does what is asked of it, then in the JavaScript you don't need any more code than you've already written. FullCalendar takes care of it all automatically.

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I wanted, but english not being my native, usually I'm focusing on codes in docs. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @ADyson highlighted, plain events in fullcalendar automatically posts `start` and `end` params to the url in ISO8601 format (like 2019-06-30 )

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: {
    url: '/load_events',
    type: 'POST'
  }
});
```